# onClick JS not go to top of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page with an initial description, followed by 2 buttons, where the user can choose typeA or typeB. They work by "target": when the user clicks typeA comes the content relative to typeA, bellow the buttons; same to typeB.

typeA is the most common selection, then, when the page loads, a javascript emulates the click to typeA and opens respective content. To avoid hidden the initial description, there is another javascript to put the page at the top. Worked on Chrome and Edge, not on Firefox.

I would like to repeat the same process when the user clicks: opens the respective content, but positioning the page at the top, or, at least, showing the buttons. I thought event onClick calling the same js backToTop would worked - but not.

I put an alert on js and enters there but not execute: always keeps the content of the button selected in its better visibility.

I tried:

```
window.location.href = '#top';
window.scrollBy(0, -500);
document.html.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
```

without success.

What am I doing wrong?

```css
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>TOP PAGE TEST</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
<style>
body,html {margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;width:70%; font-family:verdana; font-size:1.2em;}
.menuFAQ {background:#aaa; font-size:2em; width:100%;}
    .menuFAQ ul {list-style-type:none; position:relative; margin-left:-40px; /* to avoid user agent chrome */}
.menuFAQ li {display:inline-block; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px; width:49%; background:#fff; text-align:center; box-shadow:2px 3px 4px 0px rgba(170,170,170,1); font-weight:400; line-height:80px;}   
.menuFAQ li a {display:block; color:#020062; background:#fff; font-weight:400; text-decoration:none;}
.menuFAQ li .active,.menuFAQ li:hover a {color:#fff; font-weight:400; background-image:linear-gradient(#165686, #0f3a5a); }

:target {color:#fff;font-size:1em;}

div.items>div:not(:target) {display:none}
div.items>div:target {display:block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; color:#000; border:1px solid #aaa;}
</style>
 
</head>
```

```html
<body>
<div id="top">Top Page</div>

<br>textExp1<br>textExp2<br>textExp3<br>textExp4<br>textExp5

<div class="menuFAQ">
  <ul>
    <li><a id="preferedFAQ" onclick="backToTop()" class="target" href="#typeA">TypeA</a></li>
    <li><a                  onclick="backToTop()" class="target" href="#typeB">TypeB</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="items">
  <div id="typeA">
    <nav>
      A long and variable text size to explain TypeA  <br>text1A<br>text2A<br>text3A<br>text4A<br>text5A<br>text6A<br>text7A<br>text8A<br>text9A<br>textAA<br>textBA<br>textCA<br>textDA
      <br>[...]
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="items">
  <div id="typeB">
    <nav>
      A long and variable text size to explain TypeB
      <p>text1B</p><p>text2B</p><p>text3B</p>
      <br>[...]
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>

  
<script>
const allTargetLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.target')

allTargetLinks.forEach(targetLink => {
   targetLink.addEventListener('click', () => {
        allTargetLinks.forEach(targetLink => {
           targetLink.classList.remove('active')
        })
   targetLink.classList.add('active')
   })
})

window.onload = function() {assignPreferedFAQ()};

function assignPreferedFAQ() {
    document.getElementById("preferedFAQ").click();
    backToTop();
};
 
function backToTop() {
   //document.html.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
   //document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
 
     document.body.scrollTop = 0;
     document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
};
</script>
```

Comment: Please clarify, you want to scroll to the top top of the page whenever user clicks a button?

Comment: Thank you. Yes! When the page loads, works: simulated click on the first button and stayed at the top; but when the user clicks, no. I would like at least to show the buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a real mess there regarding how you process `click` events and `href` attribute, i.e:

- You had `onclick` attribute on your links, and you were adding yet another listener to them in JS
- You didn't `event.preventDefault()` in your function, and default browser behavior when you click on a link is to get you to its `href` path

I've cleaned up a bit and changed some things. Since we need to prevent default behavior `:target` selector will no longer work, so instead I did what you've already been doing with links, and added an `active` class to your content. `clickHandler()` will now remove and add class `active` as necessary. At the end just scroll to the top. Here's the snippet:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.target').forEach(targetLink => targetLink.addEventListener('click', clickHandler, false));


function clickHandler(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault(); // prevent browser from automatically scrolling to href pos
  
  if (!ev.currentTarget.classList.contains('active')) {
    // disable active elements
    document.querySelector('.target.active').classList.remove('active');
    document.querySelector('.items div.active').classList.remove('active');

    // add class to the clicked on button and its corresponding content tab
    ev.currentTarget.classList.add('active');
    
    // to prevent pointless string slicing below, you'd have to store ids somewhere else i.e in the data-id attribute
    const id = ev.currentTarget.href.slice(ev.currentTarget.href.lastIndexOf('#') + 1);
    document.getElementById(id).classList.add('active');
  }
  
  window.scrollTo(0,0);
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.menuFAQ {
  background: #aaa;
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 100%;
}

.menuFAQ ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;

  /* to avoid user agent chrome */
}

.menuFAQ li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 48%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 2px 3px 4px 0px rgba(170, 170, 170, 1);
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 80px;
}

.menuFAQ li a {
  display: block;
  color: #020062;
  background: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menuFAQ li .active,
.menuFAQ li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#165686, #0f3a5a);
}

div.items>div {
  display: none;
}

div.items>div.active {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div id="top">Top Page</div>

<br>textExp1<br>textExp2<br>textExp3<br>textExp4<br>textExp5

<div class="menuFAQ">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="target active" href="#typeA">TypeA</a></li>
    <li><a class="target" href="#typeB">TypeB</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="items">
  <div class="active" id="typeA">
    <nav>
      A long and variable text size to explain TypeA <br>text1A<br>text2A<br>text3A<br>text4A<br>text5A<br>text6A<br>text7A<br>text8A<br>text9A<br>textAA<br>textBA<br>textCA<br>textDA
      <br>[...]
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="items">
  <div id="typeB">
    <nav>
      A long and variable text size to explain TypeB
      <p>text1B</p>
      <p>text2B</p>
      <p>text3B</p>
      <br>[...]
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that instead of artificially clicking at the page load, now your content just loads with class `active`.

Comment: Thank you - I really appreciate your answer: worked in Chrome, Edge and Firefox; it is cleaner and also avoids to show the path on the URL. preventDefault() avoids to jump to typeA or B, and "target active" shows the respective text - living and learning a lot.

Comment: @josiperez You're welcome. As I commented in the code, if you don't want to rely on default behaviors of certain elements, it's usually good idea to store information that you want to use inside your JS scripts in a different way than with typical attributes, i.e in `data-` attributes. You can learn more about datasets more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you.

```js
< script >
  window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("preferedFAQ").click();
    backToTop();
  };

function backToTop() {
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  //alert("enter backToTop");
  var elmnt = document.getElementById("top");
  var x = elmnt.scrollLeft;
  var y = elmnt.scrollTop;
}; <
/script>
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 70%;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.menuFAQ {
  background: #aaa;
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 100%;
}

.menuFAQ ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -40px;
  /* to avoid user agent chrome */
}

.menuFAQ li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 49%;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 2px 3px 4px 0px rgba(170, 170, 170, 1);
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 80px;
}

.menuFAQ li a {
  display: block;
  color: #020062;
  background: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menuFAQ li .active,
.menuFAQ li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#165686, #0f3a5a);
}

:target {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1em;
}

div.items>div:not(:target) {
  display: none
}

div.items>div:target {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div id="top">Top Page</div> <br>textExp1<br>textExp2<br>textExp3<br>textExp4<br>textExp5<br>textExp6<br>textExp7<br>textExp8<br>textExp9<br>textExpA<br>textExpB<br>textExpC<br>textExpD
<br>textExpE

<div class="menuFAQ">
  <ul>
    <li><a id="preferedFAQ" onclick="backToTop()" class="target" href="#typeA">TypeA</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="backToTop()" class="target" href="#typeB">TypeB</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="items">
  <div id="typeA">
    <nav>
      A long and variable text size to explain TypeA <br>text1A<br>text2A<br>text3A<br>text4A<br>text5A<br>text6A<br>text7A<br>text8A<br>text9A<br>textAA<br>textBA<br>textCA<br>textDA
      <br>[...]
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="items">
  <div id="typeB">
    <nav>
      A long and variable text size to explain TypeB
      <p>text1B</p>
      <p>text2B</p>
      <p>text3B</p>
      <br>[...]
    </nav>
  </div>
  </di
```

Comment: I tried to use window.scrollBy(x, y) using your calculated x, y, but not worked.

Comment: Your code not work (does not position the page at the top after clicking) and assign variables x and y without use them. Then, i tried to put the command window.scrollBy(x, y) (also window.scrollTo(x, y)) after the assignments, without success.